# Replace variables containing a specific substring

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to tidy a dataset which contains a column of strings. Most strings are a permutation of the same word (e.g. "banana_test", "banana2", etc.). I want to replace all these permutations by the original word, i.e. "banana".

I tried to do this with the 'contains' command from the dplyr package.

```
fruit <- c("apple", "pear", "banana", "pear", "apple", "bad banana")
replace(fruit, contains("banana"), "banana")
```

Instead of replacing the 'bad banana' with "banana", I got the following error message: 
    *Error: No tidyselect variables were registered*

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: `dplyr` is for data frames. Your example just shows a vector, not a data frame, so most of the `dplyr` functions won't work. You should be searching for functions to work with strings in R. See `?grep`, the `stringi` package, or search on SO, [there's probably a great answer or 3 here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+replace+string+containing+word).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contains()` function from `dplyr` is a select helper that actually comes from tidyeselect now-a-days (see `?select_helpers`). It's meant to be used to find column names, not a general purpose string matching. A better choice from the tidyverse might be `str_which` from `stringr`

```
replace(fruit, str_which(fruit, "banana"), "banana")
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.